# Matching nodes based on attribute values in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an input xml which is like this

```
<xml>
<FeatureProduct>
    <Name>Spousal Guaranteed Lifetime Withdrawal Benefit</Name>
        <FeatureCode>SPB</FeatureCode>
        <FeatureOptConflict>
                <!-- Exclusive Benefits -->
        <FeatureCode>RIP</FeatureCode>
        </FeatureOptConflict>
        <FeatureOptProduct>
            <Name>Spousal Highest Daily Lifetime Income v3</Name>
            <ProductCode>SHDI3</ProductCode>
        </FeatureOptProduct>
        <FeatureOptProduct>
            <Name>Spousal Highest Daily Lifetime Income v3 with Highest Annual Death Benefit</Name>
            <ProductCode>SHDI3HADB</ProductCode>
        </FeatureOptProduct>
        <FeatureOptProduct>
            <Name>Spousal Highest Daily Lifetime Income v3 with Highest Daily Death Benefit</Name>
            <ProductCode>SHDIHDDB</ProductCode>
        </FeatureOptProduct>
</FeatureProduct>
<CalculationResult>
  <CalcResults />
  <TempCalcValuesData>
    <ChangeType>1</ChangeType>
    <MaxOwnerIssueAge>79</MaxOwnerIssueAge>
    <MaxOwnerIssueAge_Vector>
      <Value index="1">999</Value>
      <Value index="2">79</Value>
      <Value index="3">79</Value>
      <Value index="4">999</Value>
      <Value index="5">79</Value>
      <Value index="6">79</Value>
    </MaxOwnerIssueAge_Vector>
    <SegmentCovType>RIPAMP</SegmentCovType>
    <SegmentCovType_Vector>
      <Value index="1">RIP</Value>
      <Value index="2">DCA</Value>
      <Value index="3">DCA</Value>
      <Value index="4">IV</Value>
      <Value index="5">RIPAMP</Value>
    </SegmentCovType_Vector>
    <MaxAnnuitantIssueAge>79</MaxAnnuitantIssueAge>
    <MaxAnnuitantIssueAge_Vector>
      <Value index="1">999</Value>
      <Value index="2">79</Value>
      <Value index="3">79</Value>
      <Value index="4">999</Value>
      <Value index="5">79</Value>
      <Value index="6">79</Value>
    </MaxAnnuitantIssueAge_Vector>
    <SegmentCovOption>SHDI3HADB</SegmentCovOption>
    <SegmentCovOption_Vector>
      <Value index="1">HDI3</Value>
      <Value index="2">HDI3HDDB</Value>
      <Value index="3">HDI3HADB</Value>
      <Value index="4">SHDI3</Value>
      <Value index="5">SHDI3HDDB</Value>
      <Value index="6">SHDI3HADB</Value>
    </SegmentCovOption_Vector>
    <FeatureConflict>SPB</FeatureConflict>
    <FeatureConflict_Vector>
      <Value index="1">SPB</Value>
      <Value index="2">AA</Value>
      <Value index="3">IV</Value>
      <Value index="4">DCA</Value>
      <Value index="5">SPB</Value>
    </FeatureConflict_Vector>
    <MinAnnuitantIssueAge>50</MinAnnuitantIssueAge>
    <MinAnnuitantIssueAge_Vector>
      <Value index="1">50</Value>
      <Value index="2">50</Value>
      <Value index="3">50</Value>
      <Value index="4">50</Value>
      <Value index="5">50</Value>
      <Value index="6">50</Value>
    </MinAnnuitantIssueAge_Vector>
    <MinOwnerIssueAge>50</MinOwnerIssueAge>
    <MinOwnerIssueAge_Vector>
      <Value index="1">50</Value>
      <Value index="2">50</Value>
      <Value index="3">50</Value>
      <Value index="4">50</Value>
      <Value index="5">50</Value>
      <Value index="6">50</Value>
    </MinOwnerIssueAge_Vector>
  </TempCalcValuesData>
  <TempCalcValuesData>
    <ChangeType>1</ChangeType>
  </TempCalcValuesData>
  <TempCalcValuesData>
    <ChangeType>1</ChangeType>
  </TempCalcValuesData>
  <TempCalcValuesData>
    <ChangeType>1</ChangeType>
  </TempCalcValuesData>
  <TempCalcValuesData>
    <ChangeType>1</ChangeType>
  </TempCalcValuesData>
  <TempCalcValuesData>
    <ChangeType>1</ChangeType>
  </TempCalcValuesData>
  <TempCalcValuesData>
    <ChangeType>1</ChangeType>
  </TempCalcValuesData>
</CalculationResult>
</xml>
```

And I want to convert the output to something like this

```
<xml>
<FeatureProduct>
    <Name>Spousal Guaranteed Lifetime Withdrawal Benefit</Name>
        <FeatureCode>SPB</FeatureCode>
        <FeatureOptConflict>
                <!-- Exclusive Benefits -->
        <FeatureCode>RIP</FeatureCode>
        </FeatureOptConflict>
        <FeatureOptProduct>
            <Name>Spousal Highest Daily Lifetime Income v3</Name>
            <ProductCode>SHDI3</ProductCode>
            <MaxOwnerIssueAge>999<MaxOwnerIssueAge>
        </FeatureOptProduct>
        <FeatureOptProduct>
            <Name>Spousal Highest Daily Lifetime Income v3 with Highest Annual Death Benefit</Name>
            <ProductCode>SHDI3HADB</ProductCode>
            <MaxOwnerIssueAge>79<MaxOwnerIssueAge>
        </FeatureOptProduct>
        <FeatureOptProduct>
            <Name>Spousal Highest Daily Lifetime Income v3 with Highest Daily Death Benefit</Name>
            <ProductCode>SHDIHDDB</ProductCode>
            <MaxOwnerIssueAge>79<MaxOwnerIssueAge>
        </FeatureOptProduct>
</xml>
```

Basically I want to map those values in according to index values under MaxOwnerIssueAge_Vector and SegmentCovOption_Vector

So whenever the index attribute in MaxOwnerIssueAge_Vector = SegmentCovOption_Vector the get the node value in it
Example The index value for SHDI3 is 4 and the value of node in  MaxOwnerIssueAge_Vector is 79 which has index value as 4 and put it in the place under FeatureOptProduct.

So far I have written this code but its not returning me values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select ="//FeatureProduct/FeatureOptProduct">
        <MaxOwnerAge>
            <xsl:for-each select="//CalculationResult/TempCalcValuesData/MaxOwnerIssueAge_Vector">        
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="//CalculationResult/TempCalcValuesData/SegmentCovOption_Vector/Value/@index = //CalculationResult/TempCalcValuesData/MaxOwnerIssueAge_Vector/Value/@index">
                  <xsl:value-of select="//CalculationResult/MaxOwnerIssueAge_Vector/Value"/>
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </MaxOwnerAge> 
      </xsl:for-each>      
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could someone help me out with this issue or tell me some logic to do this

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `xsl:key`. Start by having a key like

```
<xsl:key name="kSegment" match="SegmentCovOption_Vector/Value" use="."/>
```

This will be used to match the value of `ProductCode` node to the `SegmentCovOption_Vector/Value` node.

A second key as the following:

```
<xsl:key name="kMaxAge" match="MaxOwnerIssueAge_Vector/Value" use="@index"/>
```

will use the index attribute to get the target value.

In matching the `FeatureOptProduct` node, as:

```
<xsl:template match="FeatureOptProduct">
    <xsl:variable name="target_index">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('kSegment', ProductCode)/@index"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <MaxOwnerIssueAge>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kMaxAge', $target_index)/text()"/>
        </MaxOwnerIssueAge>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

in the variable `target_index`, I have stored there the index number that we are interested in. We then use that in another key (kMaxAge) to get the desired node value.

The whole stylesheet is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kSegment" match="SegmentCovOption_Vector/Value" use="."/>

    <xsl:key name="kMaxAge" match="MaxOwnerIssueAge_Vector/Value" use="@index"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CalculationResult"/>

    <xsl:template match="FeatureOptProduct">
        <xsl:variable name="target_index">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kSegment', ProductCode)/@index"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <MaxOwnerIssueAge>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('kMaxAge', $target_index)/text()"/>
            </MaxOwnerIssueAge>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action [here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHT5).